# css bootstrap classes not working as i wrote

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have used both row and col classes of bootstrap and not working properly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1">

<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row ">
     <div style="background: cyan" class="offset-md-2 col-md-8">
        <h1 style="color: red">Login</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<form method="post" action="login">
    <div class="row" style="background: lightblue; height: 300px; width:500px;">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">Select Type:</div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select name="user_type" ad="user_type">
                    <option value="0">Select Type</option>
                <option value="Admin" name="admin" id="admin">Admin</option>
                <option value="Teacher" name="teacher" id="teacher">Teacher</option>
                <option value="Parent" name="parent" id="parent">Parent</option>
                </select> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">User Name:</div>
            <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" maxlength="63"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">Password:</div>
            <div class="col-md-8"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5"><input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" name="reset"> </div>

    </div>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this first field text select type and select are displaying in two rows. like all fields.  I want the text and input field in single row. can anyone help me?

Comment: are you sure the bootstrap.min.css is in the right directory? Why don't you try using bootstrapCDN? `<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1">

<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row ">
     <div style="background: cyan" class="offset-md-2 col-md-8">
        <h1 style="color: red">Login</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<form method="post" action="login">
    <div class="row" style="background: lightblue; height: 300px; width:500px;">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="float:left;"  class="col-md-4">Select Type:</div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select name="user_type" ad="user_type">
                    <option value="0">Select Type</option>
                <option value="Admin" name="admin" id="admin">Admin</option>
                <option value="Teacher" name="teacher" id="teacher">Teacher</option>
                <option value="Parent" name="parent" id="parent">Parent</option>
                </select> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="float:left;" class="col-md-4">User Name:</div>
            <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" maxlength="63"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="float:left;" class="col-md-4">Password:</div>
            <div class="col-md-8"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" </div>
        </div>
        <div  style="float:left;" class="col-md-5"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5"><input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" name="reset"> </div>

    </div>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is still same. No difference

Comment: Now, I have made some changes. Are you trying to do like this?

Comment: i have copied your code and pasted, then ran but no change occures

Comment: It works for first field. Select type and its select is working fine with your code. But remaining 2 and buttons are still same

Comment: @FahadKPMuhammed you have not used all the bootstrap classes for your form, please check below link for bootstrap classes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/ change version if you are using older one

Comment: Please explain your answer and don't just dump a chunk of code and expect everyone to know what it was that you did.

Comment: @j08691 I just used float left. And I thought the snippet cant access the links. And the request was this.

In this first field text select type and select are displaying in two rows. like all fields. I want the text and input field in single row. can anyone help me? And I made it as he asked. Is that wrong! Sorry If I'm.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easy and don't put everything in a div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1">

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body style="background-color: lightgray">
<div class="container">
<div class="row ">
 <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-8">
    <h1 style="color: #333">Login</h1>
</div>
</div>
<form method="post" action="login">
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h5 style="float: left;margin-left: 30px; ">Select Type:</h5>
            <select name="user_type" ad="user_type" style="float: left;     margin-left: 20px; margin-top:5px; ">
                <option value="0">Select Type</option>
            <option value="Admin" name="admin" id="admin">Admin</option>
            <option value="Teacher" name="teacher" id="teacher">Teacher</option>
            <option value="Parent" name="parent" id="parent">Parent</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">User Name:</div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" maxlength="63"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">Password:</div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 m-2"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5 m-2"><input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" name="reset"> </div>

</div>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```